# makecontext producing void value?

Tags: c, ucontext

My issue concerns this line:

```
    int f = makecontext( &threadList[ numThreads ].context
```

My program compiles without error without the assignment operation, but does not work at all. The line appears to do nothing. When I add "int f =" the compiler gives me the error:

```
my_pthread.c:41:10: error: void value not ignored as it ought to be
```

I don't understand how this is happening, since ucontext should always return 0 or -1.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `makecontext` function is declared as:

```
void makecontext(ucontext_t *ucp, void (*func)(), int argc, ...);
```

It returns no value, so you can't assign the result of the function to anything.

Comment: I just realized I was reading the docs for swapcontext. Thank you, I feel like an idiot now.